# Hopf bifurcation in a simple system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Given the system:

$$ 
\dot{r} = -\mu r + r^3, \\
\dot{\theta} = r
$$

There is clearly one single node at $r=0$.

The Jacobian is then: $$  \begin{pmatrix}
        -\mu + 3r^2 & 0 \\
        1 & 0
        \end{pmatrix}$$
Setting $r=0$ and finding the eigenvalues I get:
$\lambda = 0 , \lambda = -\mu $.
The problem statement says "show that a subcritical Hopf bifurcation occurs at the parameter value $\mu = 0$ ".
I don't see how a Hopf bifurcation appears here when all my eigenvalues are all real and I am failing to interpret $\lambda = 0$

Comment: Your eigenvalues are real, because you do all the calculations in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $-\mu r + r^3=r(-\mu + r^2)$. For the stability of the orbits look at the sign of $-\mu+r^2$.

Don't use the Jacobian, no need for it. Better drawing the orbits based on the former identity.

Comment: But how do I know the stability of the orbits?

Comment: Just look at the sign of $-\mu+r^2$. If it is positive the orbit goes away from the origin, etc. For $\mu>0$ you have a special value $r=\sqrt\mu$.

Comment: Oh, okay, so $r=\mu^{1/2}$ is where the limit cycle appears?

Comment: Precisely. ----